# Qt: viewing data from tables with foreign key columns pointing to multiple other tables

Tags: database, qt, relational-database, qtableview, model-view

I have a table `Thingsies`, with columns `id`, `data1`, `otherTableId`, `otherTableRowId`. I need the last two columns instead of just a foreign key column because depending on the `Thingy` the type of information I want there is different.
`otherTableId` references an `id` in the table `OtherTables`, which itself has columns called `id` and `tableName`. These `tableNames` are the names of other tables, like `OtherTable1`, `OtherTable2`.
The column `otherTableRowId` in `Thingies` references an `id` in the `OtherTable` given by `otherTableId`. The `OtherTables` themselves have more data in them. There's a one-to-one correspondence between Thingies and entries in one of the `OtherTables`. So the number of rows in Thingies is the total number of rows in all the `OtherTables`. (Is this bad design?)

I want to display Thingies in a `QTableView` that has columns for `id`, `data1`, and `data2`, where `data2` is generated programatically from `otherTableId` and `otherTableRowId`. How should I proceed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've solved this. I'm using a `QSqlQueryModel` whose query is a union of a bunch of select statements, one for each `OtherTable`. Each select statement has to somehow merge (e.g., concatenate) the data unique to each `OtherTable` using a special expression anyway, so there's no use for me at least for the `OtherTables` table.